# Google Closure - Html5History fires NAVIGATE event twice

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history, google-closure

Why does goog.history.Html5History object fire goog.history.EventType.NAVIGATE event twice each time when fragment is changed? This is the example of code:

```
var history = goog.history.Html5History.isSupported() 
      ? new goog.history.Html5History()
      : new goog.History();
goog.events.listen(history, goog.history.EventType.NAVIGATE, function(e) {
      console.log(['navigation', e.target.getToken()]);
});
history.setEnabled(true);
```

And this is log:

```
["navigation", "!/properties/new"]
["navigation", "!/properties/new"]
```

**UPD:** As I have figured out there are two different values of `isNavigation` field of `e` object in callback. First time it takes `false` value, and second time it takes `true` value. `isNavigation` means:

> isNavigation True if the event was triggered by a browser action, such
>   as forward or back, clicking on a link, editing the URL, or calling
>   window.history.(go|back|forward). False if the token has been changed
>   by a setToken or replaceToken call.

But how to get only one even fired?

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem. But in my case both events has `isNavigation==true`.

```
init = function() {
  var h = goog.history.Html5History.isSupported() ?
      new goog.history.Html5History()  : new goog.History();

  goog.events.listen(h, goog.history.EventType.NAVIGATE, navigationCallback);
  h.setEnabled(true);
};

navigationCallback = function(e) {
  console.log(e, e.token, e.isNavigation);
};

// And then:
h.setToken("example1");
h.setToken("example2");
// And click "back" button in browser
```

Output:

```
goog.history.Event "example1" false
goog.history.Event "example2" false
goog.history.Event "example1" true
goog.history.Event "example1" true
```

Comment: Here you can find simple patch:
http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/issues/detail?id=449

It's removing binding Html5History to popstate browser event.

Answer (score 0):

I have the some problem..

Do google fired one time
http://closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure/goog/demos/history1.html

Perhaps init happens twice?